String Select Collector not working Discord JS v14
I am trying to make a slightly advanced bot using DiscordJS v14.
Once I invoke this bot, it correct shows the Unlock Button + Modal + Team Select.
However, once I select the team (via the select menu option), it shows an "Interaction Failed".
The flow should be the following:

1st: Show a button...
2nd: Once user clicks in the button, shows a modal...
3rd: Once user fills the email in the modal and presses submit, shows a select
4th: Once user selects an option from the select, trigger a simple console.log

Below is what happens:

Below is my code:
import {
  ActionRowBuilder,
  TextInputBuilder,
  TextInputStyle,
  Message,
  ButtonBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
  ComponentType,
  ModalBuilder,
  StringSelectMenuBuilder,
  StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder,
} from "discord.js";

import CustomClient from "@/bot/classes/client";

const teams = [...];

export default {
  run: async (client: CustomClient, interaction: Message) => {
    try {
      const userId = client.user.id;

      const unlockButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId(`unlock-${userId}`)
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        .setLabel(" Clique para acessar o canal...");

      const unlockButtonReply = await interaction.reply({
        components: [
          new ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>().setComponents(unlockButton),
        ],
      });

      const unlockButtonReplyCollector =
        unlockButtonReply.createMessageComponentCollector({
          componentType: ComponentType.Button,
          filter: (i) => i.customId === `unlock-${userId}`,
          time: 120_000,
        });

      unlockButtonReplyCollector.on(
        "collect",
        async (unlockButtonInteraction) => {
          const emailInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId(`email-${userId}`)
            .setLabel("Digite seu email")
            .setRequired(true)
            .setMinLength(5)
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

          const modalEmail = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId(`modal-${userId}`)
            .setTitle("Liberação do Canal de Notícias")
            .setComponents([
              new ActionRowBuilder<TextInputBuilder>().addComponents(
                emailInput
              ),
            ]);

          await unlockButtonInteraction.showModal(modalEmail);

          const modalEmailInteraction =
            await unlockButtonInteraction.awaitModalSubmit({
              filter: (i) => i.customId === `modal-${userId}`,
              time: 120_000,
            });

          const email = modalEmailInteraction.fields.getField(
            `email-${userId}`
          );

          const username = modalEmailInteraction.user.username;

          const teamSelectReply = await modalEmailInteraction.reply({
            components: [
              new ActionRowBuilder<StringSelectMenuBuilder>().setComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                  .setCustomId(`team-${userId}`)
                  .setPlaceholder("Selecione o seu time do coração!")
                  .setMinValues(1)
                  .setMaxValues(1)
                  .addOptions(
                    teams.map((time) =>
                      new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
                        .setLabel(time.label)
                        .setValue(time.value)
                    )
                  )
              ),
            ],
          });

          teamSelectReply
            .awaitMessageComponent({
              componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect,
              filter: (i) => i.customId === `team-${userId}`,
              time: 120000,
            })
            .then(async (teamSelectInteraction) => {
              const team = teamSelectInteraction.values[0];
              console.log(team);
            })
            .catch(console.error);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  },
};



Nothing in your code responds to the select interaction.

teamSelectReply
.awaitMessageComponent({
componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect,
filter: (i) => i.customId === team-${userId},
time: 120000,
})
.then(async (teamSelectInteraction) => {
const team = teamSelectInteraction.values[0];
console.log(team);
})
.catch(console.error);

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I will need to answer here. What @user15517071 has commented is why you see the "Interaction failed" response. As stated at the bottom of the section here, you must acknowledge an interaction (defer or reply to) within 3 seconds. If you would like the bot to simply log the team to console and silently acknowledge the interaction, you can use await teamSelectInteraction.deferUpdate(). You will no longer see the "Interaction failed" response.

That error happened because you never replied or differed this interaction
.then(async (teamSelectInteraction) => {
   const team = teamSelectInteraction.values[0];
   console.log(team);
})

